# Can we use user input to assign variables in Julia?

Tags: julia

```
ans=readline(stdin)

function g(n)
if ans==a
return 1
else
return n
end
```

This is my code but the readline function only takes strings and i want it to take an expression which i can use in my function. What i want is to assign an expression (a) for variable ans.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
julia> function check(x)
           ans = readline()
           val=Main.eval(Meta.parse(ans))
           println("val == $x :", val==x)
       end;

julia> check(5)
2+3
val == 5 :true
```

Remarks:

1. Your functions should not reference global variables (like `ans` in your example) - if you need to get the value of `ans` - pass it as parameter.
2. Parsing the expression is unsafe - a user might want for an example use this functionality to delete your data. Use with care! In some scenarios you might want for an example to use regular expressions to validate user's input.

Comment: Actually this is just a small part in my code. I wanted to create a g(n) function which returns either 1 or n depending on user input. So basically I'll ask the user to choose either option a or b and that will determine the value of g(n)

Comment: Perhaps what you need is https://github.com/ronisbr/TextUserInterfaces.jl ?